# Are there any open source alternatives to Landscape?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, landscape

Better yet, are there any Spacewalk-like software packages that work for both RedHat-based and Debian-based systems?

Comment: Tony, Landscape and Spacewalk are massive systems. Maybe you can elaborate on what it is you want these systems to do?

Comment: here is a [demo of Foreman doing a debian install](http://youtu.be/FYsHZbCQzH8)

Comment: maybe [Amon](https://amon.cx) would be a help if you want to keep everything simple

Answer (score 34):

In addition to straight Puppet and Spacewalk, there is a puppet-based system called "[foreman](http://theforeman.org/)" that does most of what you're looking for.

[image]

*while the screenshot does show CentOS and Windows clients, it does have Ubuntu support*

I've used it and I recommend giving it a go.

Comment: What is needed to start using it? Can i take 3 clean comps and put on one Ubuntu any version and this programm and then how to make from network other 2 comps to install with ubuntu also?

Comment: I set up a foreman install. It works, I can see the various attached clients. I also have no idea *what to do with them*. I'm basically interested in using it for patch management, but I can't even figure out how to see what needs patching. I think I'm supposed to do something with puppet sensors (?), but the online library of them doesn't seem to have any for apt.

Comment: Ok, apparently any sort of life-cycle/patch-management in Foreman is done via [Katello](https://github.com/Katello/katello), which has no support for debian/ubuntu, so foreman is not a functional alternative to landscape at all.

Answer (score 9):

As of 2019, [Landscape on-premises is free for small installations](https://landscape.canonical.com/try-landscape) (10 servers + 10 VMs).

Installation instructions can be found here: 
[How do I install Landscape for personal use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use)

It is also open source, with [source code available on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~landscape).

Comment: Note that this has changed. It's now 10 servers/VMs, and 50 "containers".

Answer (score 5):

[According to the FAQ](https://spacewalkproject.github.io/faq.html), Spacewalk supports Debian, so it may support Ubuntu as well.

If you are looking for configuration options for a large environment, you could take a look at [Puppet](https://puppet.com/).

Comment: I am a big fan of Spacewalk, but last I checked the Debian support was not in that good o a shape. Foreman is much better adjusted and works with Ubuntu, see previous answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try out [vFense](https://github.com/vFense/vFense) , which is still in Beta, but it supports Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat, OS X and Windows. vFense is an open source cross platform patch management tool, that is also cross referencing vulnerability data from Ubuntu, Windows, and soon RedHat as well.

Full disclosure, I am the lead developer of the project.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you please describe a bit more this software?

Comment: All the links above are dead. The link to the project is https://github.com/vFense/vFense

Comment: It appears vFense is dead as well.