# What is the best tool to manage several Ubuntu stations over network?

Tags: administration

Wich are the options for Ubuntu Desktop management over network?

Not installation deployment over network. Management of more than 1000 Ubuntus desktop over network.

Something like Red Hat Satellite... to generate reports about updates, memory usage, disk usage, install software and other management tasks.

Comment: "best"  is subjective.

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/q/628584/158442

Answer (score 0):

landscape from Cannonical is the only one that I know for managing this kind of things. I have used it for managing servers before and it really is excellent